# Error : IBS profiling is disabled in the BIOS settings

Tags: x86, profiler, amd-processor

I want  to analyze my CPU with profiller, i choose IBS OP Samples and run it. But then show the error message "Error : IBS profiling is disabled in the BIOS settings". I go to my BIOS setting, but i dont find IBS in my BIOS.

Can anyone help to fix this.

I use AMD Ryzen 5 1500x with Mainboard MSI B350M PRO-VH PLUS(MS-7B07) v.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Hm, so long ago. And if you check "AMD CBS" item in BIOS? Some version of motherboads' BIOS has the option in Chipset.